# Capturar onClick en el FlexibleAdapter Java Android

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

Estoy implementando la librería [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter) para añadir características al `RecyclerView` pero su documentación es muy escasa

Intento capturar el `OnClick` en la creación del Adaptador y no en la construcción del `item`

Ahora mismo tengo

```
public class KeyValueItem extends AbstractFlexibleItem<KeyValueItem.MyViewHolder> {

    private String key;
    private String value;

    public KeyValueItem(String k, String v) {
        key = k;
        value = v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof KeyValueItem) {
            KeyValueItem inItem = (KeyValueItem) o;
            return this.key.equals(inItem.key);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return key.hashCode();
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.list_item_layout;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder createViewHolder(View view, FlexibleAdapter<IFlexible> adapter) {
        return new MyViewHolder(view, adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindViewHolder(FlexibleAdapter<IFlexible> adapter, MyViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
        holder.mKey.setText(key);
        holder.mValue.setText(value);
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends FlexibleViewHolder {

        public TextView mKey;
        public TextView mValue;

        public MyViewHolder(View view, FlexibleAdapter adapter) {
            super(view, adapter);

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            mKey = view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            mValue = view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Click on  position " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onClick(view);
        }

    }


}
```

Me detecta el click de cada elemento pero me gustaría controlar fuera de el, es decir directamente al adaptador

Answer (score 1):

Pasa la instancia del evento por el constructor al Holder desde el adapter para que asi se ejecute en el adapter.

1- Agrega el evento al constructor del holder:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends FlexibleViewHolder {
    public TextView mKey;
    public TextView mValue;
    public OnClickListener mValue;

    public MyViewHolder(View view, FlexibleAdapter adapter, OnClickListener onclick) 
    {
        super(view, adapter);

        view.setOnClickListener(onclick);
        mKey = view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        mValue = view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    }

}
```

2- implementas el evento en el adapter:

```
public class KeyValueItem extends AbstractFlexibleItem<KeyValueItem.MyViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String key;
    private String value;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Click on  position " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onClick(view);
    }

    //...
```

3- Entonces en el adapter le envias la referencia del evento:

```
return new MyViewHolder(view, adapter, this);
```

Asi los eventos Click se ejecutaran en el adapter. Si quieres los eventos fuera del adapter, solo tienes que hacer los mismos pasos agregando el evento al constructor del adapter.